# create notification when unstaged change is created in local git repo

Tags: git, notifications, githooks

I've got some config directories on my local Mac machine placed under versioning with Git. These aren't directories I directly inspect often, if ever. They mostly end up being altered via various command line installations. However, I don't always realize when an installation has made a change to any one of these various config directories that I'm trying to keep well versioned. Thus, many changes are made over time, before my noticing, that should be broken up into separate commits. Is there something I can setup (hooks, perhaps?) to get, idk, like a desktop/growl notification when a change to any repo on my machine has occurred so I may then go stage and commit?

If I'm approaching this issue from entirely the wrong angle or creating an issue where there isn't one really because of something I'm not aware of, please, feel free to let more know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need to write a script that runs git status on each one of your repos and then put that script in your crontab.